# How to secure @PostMapping endpoint by spring security without secure @GetMapping

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, endpoint

I would like to add Spring Security to my app on few endpoints.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity post() {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity get() {
        ...
    }
```

In web security conifure adapter I know how to secure endpoit. I did:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic().and()
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users", "/users/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ;
    }
```

In endpoint "/test" I would like to add security in @PostMapping where only authenticated users will be able to post something. @GetMapping will be open for everyone.

**EDIT**
So I updated my MyWebSecurityConfig:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and()
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users", "/users/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/shapes").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/shapes/history").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            ;
}
```

but I can't still send Get on "/shapes" endpoit without authentication.
I am still getting 401 Unauthorized. What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

There is an overrided version of  `antMatchers()` that allow you to configure matching a HTTP method and the path together :

```java
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/users", "/users/**").permitAll()
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/test").permitAll()
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/test").authenticated()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunetly I changed code but @GetMapping is still expecting authorization